# Angular 2 AOT: Getting lot of errors in index.d.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, jit, angular2-aot, aot

I have an angular application currently configured with JIT, and it's working fine. I tried configuring it to work with AOT (Ahead of time) compilation.
Here's my work till now:

Here is my **tsconfig-aot.ts**:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "lib": ["es7", "dom"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "files": [
    "wwwroot/app/app.module.ts",
    "wwwroot/app/main.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
     "genDir": "aot",
     "skipMetadataEmit" : true
   },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My **package.json** :

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.1.5",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng2-pagination": "2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "7.0.7",
    "concurrently": "3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "lite-server": "2.2.2",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "typings": "2.1.0"
  }
}
```

My **main.ts** :

```
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../../aot/wwwroot/app/app.module.ngfactory';

const platform = platformBrowser();

platform.bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

My app is configured to work with Gulp and SystemJS, and using Visual Studio 2015.
I tried compiling it with command prompt with:

```
"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

The app gets compiled successfully, but on running I'm getting a about 200 errors in **typings\globals\node\index.d.ts** and **node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts**. Error codes:

**TS2502:** 'BuffType' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation.

**TS2451:** Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'constants'.

**TS2430:** Interface 'ReadWriteStream' incorrectly extends interface 'ReadableStream'.
  Types of property 'pause' are incompatible.
    Type '() => ReadWriteStream' is not assignable to type '{ (): ReadableStream; (): this; }'.
      Type 'ReadWriteStream' is not assignable to type 'this'.

similarly others: **TS2420, TS2415, TS2403, TS2320, TS2309, TS2300**

All of these errors are in **typings\globals\node\index.d.ts** and **node_modules\@types\node\index.d.ts**. Anybody please help!

What exactly is the issue? Is it a version issue or some import issue or some configurations are not correct?

Comment: what version of typescript? check from visual studio > help > about. Is it 2.2.1 or something else?

Comment: @pixelbits no it's 2.1.5.0. Why?

Comment: Just FYI, `"lib": ["es7"]` should be `"lib": ["es2017"]`

Comment: Sorry, no luck :(